# RSyslog CPU usage > 100%

Tags: cpu-load, syslog, rsyslog

We currently have RSyslog Server (On Linux Ubuntu 18.04 VM LTA with Size: Standard D4s v3 4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory) receiving logs from ZScaler Proxy & FortiGate Firewalls and ingesting them into Azure Sentinel.

The issue is, after a few minutes/hours, the CPU starts reaching max 100% and netstat connection to each firewall gets stuck in ESTABLISHED state and ultimately stops processing the logs.
Below is the sample output:

[image: netstat connection]

It requires restarting the RSyslog service to resume the traffic flow. The traffic between Firewalls and Syslog (TCP 514) is encrypted using TLS 1.2 and Certificates are generated locally on this Syslog Server and distributed across Firewalls.

Another important observation is during the CPU max out phase, the load across CPU cores is not equal and shows only one over-utilized as seen in the below screenshot:

[image: CPU Load]

Based on recent recommendations, we tried upgrading the RSyslog version to the latest rsyslogd 8.2202.0 (aka 2021.12) but the issue still persists.

It would be great if someone can please advise what could be the possible issue and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: How busy is your `/var/log/syslog` file when `rsyslogd` hits 100% CPU utilisation?

Comment: @matigo how can I check the current usage stats in /var/log/syslog ?